# Does this count as spam?

Tags: support, spam

This [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379479/project-hilo) has posted the same answer on four different SO questions, all linking to a certain project's website.

Comment: yep, looks like spam. also looks like a potential advertiser :|

Comment: Yes, basically spam.

Comment: His user profile (name and "about me") gives some hints about his intentions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me it definitely is:

- just linking to an external site
- not providing any actual content in the answer like at least a summary
- doesn't even try to address the actual question

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because of the lack of content or any apparent direct relation to the question...  I feel these cross the line as spam.

There are a lot of definitions of spam. In cases like these, I think the deciding factor is, **are these messages being "posted indiscriminately?"** "Indiscriminately" as in posted either mindlessly, undirected, or in a somewhat random manner.

There are cases where a user's otherwise perfectly legitimate answers also *happen* to include self-promotion. I don't necessarily consider those spam on that basis. You have to look at the context.

These do not pass my personal acid test.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to thank you for using up four of my spam votes for today. :)

My acid test is:

- Are the answers relevant to the question?
  In this case, no. Specifically, in this case, they're copy-and-paste!
- Are the answers distinct from one another, indicating at least an attempt by the user to address the question?
  Once again, no. They're straight up copy-and-paste.

Thus, they reek of a canned meat-based product.